# resolvconf writing invalid resolv.conf file

Tags: linux-mint, dns, vpn, resolv.conf, resolvconf

Every time I connect to my VPN I lose DNS with an error of,

```
"cannot parse /etc/resolv.conf"
```

The offending line is line 1 being an empty "domain". So after connecting to the VPN my resolv.conf file looks like this:

```
domain  
nameserver  10.10.150.163
nameserver  10.10.150.164
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
search Belkin
```

I have no idea where this is coming from... I'm using PFsense, Shrewsoft VPN client, and Linux Mint 17 KDE. If I delete the "domain" from resolv.conf everything works fine.

I've disabled dnsmasq, changed ifupdown managed from false to true in NetworkManager.conf, made sure that the domain statement isn't in base, head, or tail, removed the symlink from tail, ensured that my domain is configured correctly on pfsense, and a billion other things that escape me at the moment...

Comment: Evidently the first three lines are added by your VPN client and it's buggy or incompatible with resolvconf. Is that client open-source? or at least publicly documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be a permissions thing as you said it is at least editing the resolv.conf file to start with. I would initially rule out all of the stuff related to OS level functions purely based on this.

I know you mentioned that your domain is proper in pfsense, but in what context?

On your pfsense, Go to OpenVPN Server --> Client Settings --> DNS Default Domain. Is this box checked? If so, is it populated properly? If it appears blank, check for a space character. I mean, really...if it is blank, uncheck it. Next, test to see if adding test.com and restart raccoon on your gateway. See if connecting changes your resolv.conf with the test.com domain.

Comment: Your instincts were correct. I had entered the default domain in the "Split DNS" section of (PFsense >> VPN >> IPsec >> Mobile clients) instead of the correct "DNS Default Domain". I'd also configured the Shrew Soft client to obtain the DNS suffix automatically. As a result Shrew Soft was updating the resolv.conf file with all the information it had. Which led to it writing an empty "domain" statement to the top of the file. This invalid statement caused parsing to fail.